# How to generate representation of a tensor in an equation using nested matrices

Tags: matrices, package-writing, tikz-matrix, tensor

In general a tensor is defined as an object with `N` superscripts and `M` subscripts. Each superscript and subscript can take a range of values `1,2,...,n`. For example, a tensor `M^[ij]_[klm]` can have `i=1,2,3` , `j=1,2,3` and `k=1,2`, `l=1,2` and `m=1,2,3`. I can represent such a tensor using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix} % all blocks
\begin{matrix} % empty block at top left
    & & & \\
    & & & 
\end{matrix} % empty block at top left
&
\begin{matrix} % matrix of superscripts
    \quad 1\quad & \quad 1\quad & \quad 1\quad & \quad 2\quad  & \quad 2\quad & \quad 2 \quad & \quad 3\quad  & \quad 3\quad & \quad 3\quad \\
    \quad 1\quad & \quad 2\quad & \quad 3\quad  & \quad 1\quad & \quad 2\quad  & \quad 3\quad & \quad 1\quad  & \quad 2\quad  & \quad 3\quad
\end{matrix} % matrix of superscripts
\\   %end of top group of block matrices
\begin{matrix} % matrix of subscripts
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    1 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    2 & 2 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 & 2 \\
    2 & 2 & 3 
\end{matrix} % matrix of subscripts
&
\begin{bmatrix} % tensor
   \begin{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{11}_{111} & M^{12}_{111} & M^{13}_{111} \\
            M^{11}_{112} & M^{12}_{112} & M^{13}_{112} \\
            M^{11}_{113} & M^{12}_{113} & M^{13}_{113}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{21}_{111} & M^{22}_{111} & M^{23}_{111} \\
            M^{21}_{112} & M^{22}_{112} & M^{23}_{112} \\
            M^{21}_{113} & M^{22}_{113} & M^{23}_{113}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{31}_{111} & M^{32}_{111} & M^{33}_{111} \\
            M^{31}_{112} & M^{32}_{112} & M^{33}_{112} \\
            M^{31}_{113} & M^{32}_{113} & M^{33}_{113}                  
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{11}_{121} & M^{12}_{121} & M^{13}_{121} \\
            M^{11}_{122} & M^{12}_{122} & M^{13}_{122} \\
            M^{11}_{123} & M^{12}_{123} & M^{13}_{123}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{21}_{121} & M^{22}_{121} & M^{23}_{121} \\
            M^{21}_{122} & M^{22}_{122} & M^{23}_{122} \\
            M^{21}_{123} & M^{22}_{123} & M^{23}_{123}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{31}_{121} & M^{32}_{121} & M^{33}_{121} \\
            M^{31}_{122} & M^{32}_{122} & M^{33}_{122} \\
            M^{31}_{123} & M^{32}_{123} & M^{33}_{123}                  
        \end{bmatrix}
   \end{bmatrix}   
   \\
   \begin{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{11}_{211} & M^{12}_{211} & M^{13}_{211} \\
            M^{11}_{212} & M^{12}_{212} & M^{13}_{212} \\
            M^{11}_{213} & M^{12}_{213} & M^{13}_{213}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{21}_{211} & M^{22}_{211} & M^{23}_{211} \\
            M^{21}_{212} & M^{22}_{212} & M^{23}_{212} \\
            M^{21}_{213} & M^{22}_{213} & M^{23}_{213}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{31}_{211} & M^{32}_{211} & M^{33}_{211} \\
            M^{31}_{212} & M^{32}_{212} & M^{33}_{212} \\
            M^{31}_{213} & M^{32}_{213} & M^{33}_{213}                  
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{11}_{221} & M^{12}_{221} & M^{13}_{221} \\
            M^{11}_{222} & M^{12}_{222} & M^{13}_{222} \\
            M^{11}_{223} & M^{12}_{223} & M^{13}_{223}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{21}_{221} & M^{22}_{221} & M^{23}_{221} \\
            M^{21}_{222} & M^{22}_{222} & M^{23}_{222} \\
            M^{21}_{223} & M^{22}_{223} & M^{23}_{223}          
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            M^{31}_{221} & M^{32}_{221} & M^{33}_{221} \\
            M^{31}_{222} & M^{32}_{222} & M^{33}_{222} \\
            M^{31}_{223} & M^{32}_{223} & M^{33}_{223}                  
        \end{bmatrix}    
   \end{bmatrix}      
\end{bmatrix}  % tensor
\end{matrix} % all blocks
\]

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

The structure of this object in two dimensions is a series of nested matrices. The basic block in this example is a 3x3 matrix. Using this basic block we can build a 2x3 matrix of 3x3 matrices. The final step is to build a 2x1 matrix of 2x3 matrices of 3x3 matrices. So in general building a tensor using block matrices as the building block is a recursive process. One starts with an array `sup[]={3,3}` whose length is equal to the number of superscripts and each entry is the range of each superscript and a similar array `sub[]={2,2,3}` for the subscripts. Then pairs are constructed starting from `sup[sup.length]` and `sub[sub.length]` which defines the basic building block. The next level uses `sup[sup.length-1]` and `sub[sub.length-1]` and so on; if `sup.length \neq sub.length`  then some pairs will have to be `(1,sup[i])` or `(sub[j],1)` depending on which index has run out.

The question is: **"How does one automate that?"** I have not been able to find anything in `tikz` or `asymptote` that can handle such a task. Ideally one should be able to write something like:

```
\begin{equation}

\tmatrix{M}{^3^3_2_2_3}

\end{equation}
```

instead of the manual intensive code shown above. I realize this is a big project so I am looking for guidance rather than a solution. Perhaps the best way to go about it is to write a brand new package...

Answer (score 0):

The multidimensional aspect of the recursion seemed daunting.

Here's a non-recursive version that constructs a TikZ-matrix with 2×2×3 rows and 3×3 columns. These products get calculated first (→ `mul list`) and stored in `\ROWSprod` and `\COLSprod`. The key also calculates the number of entries (here 3 and 2) but they're not used.

The `tmatrix'` key calculates both the superscript and subscript. I've tried to calculate this with PGFmath but something went wrong so I'm using count-based calculation from `\pgfint…`.

The labels to the left and above are maybe better placed after the matrix has been constructed and its bounding box is known but vanilla labels make it possibly very simply already.

---

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a mathematical way to evaluate which delimiters should be used – still too many dimensions for my brain – which is why I let the user give the needed matrices:

```
LR delims={l2 6x9 1-1, 7-1}
```

means that the matrix should get delimiters on the second level (the level is only used as an option to change the appearence and placement of the delimiters) around blocks of 6×9 submatrices with the top-right corners at 1-1 and 7-1.

I realize this is not as automatic as it ought to be – and it wouldn't even be an issue with a recursive nested-`bmatrix` solution – but it's also not that much work to specify the needed delimiters with the `LR delims` key.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,ext.misc}
\newcommand*\tmatrixSTOP{\tmatrixSTOP}
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{
  .add/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
        {\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}+#1},
  .mul/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
        {\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}*#1},
  .++/.style={\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.add=1}}
\pgfqkeys{/tmatrix}{
  mul list/.style n args={3}{
    /tmatrix/tempa/.initial=0, /tmatrix/tempb/.initial=1,
    /tmatrix/temp/.style={/tmatrix/tempa/.++,/tmatrix/tempb/.mul={##1}},
    /tmatrix/temp/.list={#1}, /tmatrix/tempa/.get=#2, /tmatrix/tempb/.get=#3},
  tmatrix'/.style n args={4}{
    /return #4/.initial=, /utils/tempa/.initial=1,
    /utils/temp/.style={
      /return #4 list/.initial={##1},
      /utils/temp/.style={/return #4 list/.prefix={####1,}}},
    /tmatrix/tmatrix do/.style={
      /utils/tempa/.mul={##1},
      /return #4/.append/.expanded=%
        \pgfinteval{\pgfintmod{\pgfintdivtruncate
          {#1}{#3/\pgfkeysvalueof{/utils/tempa}}}{##1}+1},
      /utils/temp/.expanded=%
        \pgfinteval{\pgfintmod{\pgfintdivtruncate
          {#1}{#3/\pgfkeysvalueof{/utils/tempa}}}{##1}+1}},
    /tmatrix/tmatrix do/.list={#2}}}
\tikzset{
  add label above/.style={@add label above={#1,\tmatrixSTOP}},
  add label left/.style={@add label left={#1,\tmatrixSTOP}},
  @add label above/.style args={#1,#2}{%
    /utils/TeX/ifx={\tmatrixSTOP}{#2}{label={above:#1}}{
               label={[@add label above={#2}]above:#1}}},
  @add label left/.style args={#1,#2}{%
    /utils/TeX/ifx={\tmatrixSTOP}{#2}{label={[xshift=-1em]left:#1}}{
               label={[xshift=-1em,@@add label left={#2}]left:#1}}},
  @@add label left/.style args={#1,#2}{%
    /utils/TeX/ifx={\tmatrixSTOP}{#2}{label={left:#1}}{
               label={[@@add label left={#2}]left:#1}}},
  add lr delim/.style n args={3}{append after command={
      [local bounding box=@] (\tikzlastnode-#1.north west)
                             (\tikzlastnode-#2.south east)\bgroup (@) [
        every left delimiter/.append style={lr #3 left/.try},
        every right delimiter/.append style={lr #3 right/.try},
        late options={left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}}]\egroup}},
  LR delims/.style args={l#1 #2x#3 #4}{
     % #1 = level, #2=width, #3 = height, #4 = top right corners
    /utils/temp/.style args={##1-##2}{
      add lr delim=
        {##1-##2}{\the\numexpr##1+#2-1\relax-\the\numexpr##2+#3-1\relax}{#1}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#4}}}
\makeatletter
\let\gappto\pgfutil@g@addto@macro
\newcommand*\repeatMe[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=0 \expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {#2\expandafter\repeatMe\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\tmatrix[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  /tmatrix/mul list={#3}\ROWScnt\ROWSprod,
  /tmatrix/mul list={#4}\COLScnt\COLSprod,
  M/.style={every matrix/.append style={##1}},#1]
\matrix[
  name=M, column sep=\the\arraycolsep,
  column 1/.append style={
    tmatrix node/.append style={
      add label left/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/return row list}}},
  row 1/.append style={
    tmatrix node/.append style={
      add label above/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/return col list}}},
  every cell/.append style={
    /tmatrix/tmatrix'/.expanded=% construct the subscript
      {\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax}{#3}{\ROWSprod}{row},
    /tmatrix/tmatrix'/.expanded=% construct the superscript
      {\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax}{#4}{\COLSprod}{col}}
] {
\repeatMe{\ROWSprod}{
  \repeatMe{\COLSprod}{
    \node[tmatrix node/.try]
      (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
      {${#2}_{\pgfkeysvalueof{/return row}}^{\pgfkeysvalueof{/return col}}$};
    \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\COLSprod\relax % no & after last col
      \expandafter\pgfmatrixnextcell\fi}
  \unless\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\ROWSprod\relax % no \\ after last row
    \expandafter\pgfmatrixendrow\fi
}\pgfmatrixendrow};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\tikzset{
  lr delim shift/.style 2 args={
    lr #1 left/.append style={xshift={#2}},
    lr #1 right/.append style={xshift={-(#2)}}}}
\begin{document}
\tmatrix[
  % these two need to be set outside of the matrix
  lr delim shift={3}{.35em},
  lr delim shift={1}{-.35em},
  M={% this gets forwarded to the matrix
    LR delims={l1 12x9 1-1},
    LR delims={l2 6x9 1-1, 7-1},
    LR delims={l3 3x3 1-1,  1-4,  1-7,
                      4-1,  4-4,  4-7,
                      7-1,  7-4,  7-7,
                     10-1, 10-4, 10-7}}%
]{M}{2,2,3}{3,3}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that it took a lot of effort (by the way that's some really advanced usage of tikz code). Unfortunately I am looking at something where the brackets are placed automatically (each token is effectively a set of brackets). Even worse, the code I am working on needs to put indices to the left and the top so that the reader can see how they are mapped. I think its fair that we close it since my question can only be answered by someone writing a package!!

Comment: @TedBlack The indices aren't that hard to add, after all for every element in the first row the superscript is the label above and for every element in the first column the subscript is the label to the left. I understand the need to place the brackets automatic. I've succeeded for the inner most matrix (the last digit of the sub- and superscripts are equal to the dimension of that level) but I've got confused further down the line. A package writer needs to figure that out, too. (Or build the TikZ matrix recursively and keep track of the entries.)